superset itself modifies clickhousesql?
enter image description hereThis is an earlier version of the query
enter image description hereIn version 2.0.0, the statement corresponding to the same metadata was changed to the one in the figure
I thought this was sql auto-optimization for superset, but I couldn't find it in config.py

Just remove the SERIES LIMIT configuration

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
